# Process Builder post to chatter group error: guest user?

Tags: process-builder, chatter

I'm trying to do something really simple: post to a Chatter Group from Process Builder. It's giving me an error:

> Error Occurred: Guest users are not permitted to perform this operation.

I don't get it. Why is it seeing process builder as a Guest user?

Here's the whole error email:

```
    Error element myRule_1_A1 (FlowActionCall).
Guest users are not permitted to perform this operation.

Flow Details
Flow Name: SMS_Push_Notification
Type: Record Change Process
Version: 5
Status: Active
Org: Proton 7 Group (00Df0000002H289)

Flow Interview Details
Interview Label: SMS_Push_Notification-5_InterviewLabel
Current User: ProtonText Site Guest User (005f0000002XP3q)
Start time: 7/10/2018 6:33 PM
Duration: 0 seconds

How the Interview Started
ProtonText Site Guest User (005f0000002XP3q) started the flow interview.
Some of this flow's variables were set when the interview started.
myVariable_old = a00f0000009lZkZAAU
myVariable_current = a00f0000009lZkZAAU

ASSIGNMENT: myVariable_waitStartTimeAssignment
{!myVariable_waitStartTimeVariable} Equals {!$Flow.CurrentDateTime}
Result
{!myVariable_waitStartTimeVariable} = "7/10/2018 6:33 PM"

DECISION: isChangedDecision2_myRule_1_Unread_c
Executed this outcome: isChangedRule_2_myRule_1_Unread_c
Outcome conditions: and
1. {!myVariable_old} (a00f0000009lZkZAAU) Is null false
2. {!myVariable_old.Unread__c} (0) Does not equal {!myVariable_current.Unread__c} (1)
Logic: All conditions must be true (AND)

DECISION: myDecision
Executed this outcome: myRule_1
Outcome conditions: and
1. {!isChangedRule_2_myRule_1_Unread_c} (true) Equals true
2. {!myVariable_current.Unread__c} (1) Greater than 0
Logic: All conditions must be true (AND)

POST TO CHATTER: myRule_1_A1
Inputs:
text = @{!myVariable_current.Owner:User.Username} New SMS from {!myVariable_current.Group_Name__c} (@pat@mobile.com New SMS from Bob Tester)
type = GROUP
subjectNameOrId = 0F9f00000004RvgCAE

Error Occurred: Guest users are not permitted to perform this operation.

Salesforce Error ID: 961972878-11697 (1454238493)
```

Comment: If you are trying to kick-in the process flow from an external site(web page), you might get this kind of errors. My understanding is: As a Site Guest User license, I will not have all the accesses what a Salesforce User License has.

Comment: @ArnoldJr. there's no external site involved. The process just triggers when the Unread__c field on a custom object (Conversation__c) changes and is greater than 0. Then, it sends a Chatter message to the record owner. Simple. No guest involved.

Comment: What I found from your logs: `How the Interview Started:  
ProtonText Site Guest User (005f0000002XP3q) started the flow interview.`

Comment: @ArnoldJr. -- exactly. I'm trying to figure out why it thinks the current user is a Site Guest User.

Comment: How are you trying to trigger your flow? On what user interface?

Comment: There is an incoming REST call the results in a Message__c record being saved with the Unread__c field true. Message is a child object of Conversation__c, which has a rollup sum of unread Messages. If the unread field on Conversation__c changes, and it is > 0, then the flow triggers. I want that to result in a notification, so I'm figuring the easiest way to generate the notification is to post to Chatter (though I'm researching alternatives now.) User interface is desktop and Salesforce1.

Comment: You should try running the REST call(if applicable) using runAs( ) any Salesforce User License user(say, a dummy user). Because, whenever you try to create a record on the Salesforce using external calls, there might be chance that the current user's context: Site Guest User, which in-turn causing you this problem. While you try to post to Chatter, you should also consider a User associated to that post(posting user).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80039/discussion-between-patmcclellan-c-and-arnold-jr).

Comment: Has any one was able to get a workaround for this? I am running into similar issue, when rest api class creates a record, and a process builder post a chatter comment resulting permission issue under site guest user.